# WinRT XAML ComboBox opens in middle of list

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, windows-runtime, behavior

So one particular behavior of the XAML combobox in WinRT is causing me a huge headache, because my client sees it as a defect, and doesn't care if it's the behavior of the control, he wants it changed. However, I cannot find anything that tells how to change it.  The behavior I'm speaking of is that when nothing is selected the ComboBox popup opens displaying the ItemsSource in the middle of the list. I have a sorted list of countries, with the exception of US, UK, CAN being at the top. These 3 items are the most often selected items and the client wants them on top rather than having to scroll through the list to find them. That's easy enough, but because the list opens in the middle, you still have to scroll quite a bit to get to them.  Is there some property I'm missing that turns this behavior off? I was able to finally convince them that the CarouselPanel wasn't a defect, but this one isn't going to fly.

Thanks in advance!

[image: when no selection has been made]
[image: list is opened in the middle]

**UPDATE:**
So this combobox is databound through a ViewModel. in this instance, the ViewModel has no value (it is an empty string) for that particular property and so the Combobox shows empty, which is fine and desirable. When you click on the Combobox to select a value, it displays the list in the middle of the available values. this is the behavior that is undesirable. it should be showing the 1st value in the list at the top!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one would think that the out of the box Combobox (there is no other built in dropdown control) would be able to work like any other combobox control in any other MS technology to date, but of course this is MS, so why should things be consistent. At any rate, I ended up having to create a "blank" entry and pre-select that item if the value in the VM is empty, and then write code in the setter of that property to ignore if "blank" item if it is selected. It's kludgy and wreaks of code smell, but it works

Answer (score 0):

When you set the SelectedItem property to an object, the ComboBox attempts to make that object the currently selected one in the list. If the object is found in the list, it is displayed in the edit portion of the ComboBox and the SelectedIndex property is set to the corresponding index. If the object does not exist in the list, the SelectedIndex property is left at its current value.

Comment: So this combobox is databound through a ViewModel. in this instance, the ViewModel has no value (it is an empty string) for that particular property and so the Combobox shows empty, which is fine and desirable. When you click on the Combobox to select a value, it displays the list in the middle of the available values. this is the behavior that is undesirable. it should be showing the 1st value in the list at the top!

Comment: Can you apply a SelectedItem property at the click event of the Combobox?

Comment: Selected to what? I don't want to pre-select a choice if one has not been already chosen, because that changes data down the line.

Comment: Maybe you need to rethink the type of control you are using

Comment: Well, one would think that the out of the box Combobox (there is no other built in dropdown control) would be able to work like any other combobox control in any other MS technology to date, but of course this is MS, so why should things be consistent. At any rate, I ended up having to create a "blank" entry and pre-select that item if the value in the VM is empty, and then write code in the setter of that property to ignore if "blank" item if it is selected. It's kludgy and wreaks of code smell, but it works